# Mixed types of object value typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, object-type

I have a question about mixed types in object values

I have an empty object with interface that I fill out later with the code. I add strings and numbers to it.

```
interface CardDataObject {
    [key: string]: any
}

const data: CardDataObject = {}

data.number = number
data.string = string
```

That's how I add items later

With 'any' everything works fine, but my teacher says that I have to define it better and without 'any' type

Is there any way to create a universal interface for an object not knowing the type of values in advance?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is right, `any` is to avoid at all cost because it basically disables TypeScript so it's like you write plain JavaScript.

You add strings and numbers to it? Then type it like this:

```
interface CardDataObject {
    [key: string]: string | number
}
```

Shortest variant:

```
type CardDataObject = Record<string, string | number>
```

Comment: I did try string | number, but then I have errors like "Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'."   I do add strings and numbers via data.numbers = numbers and data.string = string for example

Comment: it gives me same errors with Record<string, string | number> by the way

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to not know the type at all in advance, typescript needs to know at least a range of types which are possible.

Look at these options:

1. If you know that you going to use your interface only with numbers and strings (and maybe others) you can use then `union` types, it looks like - `number | string`

An example:

```
interface CardDataObject {
    [key: string]: number | string
}
const data: CardDataObject = { key1: 'text', key2: 100 };
```

Union types - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

2. The other option, if you want it to work with all possible types is to use 'generics'. You can declare an interface with a generic type and then choose later which type exactly it should be.

An example:

```
interface CardDataObject<T> {
    [key: string]: T
}
const dataNumbers: CardDataObject<number> = { key1: 100 };
const dataStrings: CardDataObject<string> = { key1: 'text' };
```

Typescript generics - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABCEPIA4BcCWB7AdhAjJEwJiTQQFMAnAMwEMBjYiAYUtIBMARShSmAIwCtjqCADwAVAHwQA3pAiyA2gGtiATwBcEAM4JShAOYBddSLABfMNXRaIzDpQByAVwC23MhvWMW7Tj36ChaM6upBIAvFIQSsqY6pgADHEQJgDc5pYI1rYAytp67gxMbLa%20AsJaOmi6YRFRMRAA5CQAHgj1SakWaFY2nDkVujCkji5uHoXeXHylQuV6EAA%20EIEjIRDhkpEqdY3ELfUANJvKAEyxCe1gl6A4sIioGMc4wAREZFS0BV7FU4LHUjLyKLqWaVQxLIJkBaaXKVUxpLoZHqUPp6QbDYIaU6fIo%20H4IP7rI7bZqtQ5RLHxRIpIA)